# Execute select query and use values in another query, all within one stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, sql

I am wondering if it is possible to call a stored procedure (from .net vb) and send it one value. The stored procedure will take that value, execute a select statement, then reuse the 3-5 selected values and execute another select statement. I am trying to keep it all within one stored procedure.

Comment: Could you provide more information with example or with your code here ?

Comment: My goal is to send an id to a stored procedure. Then 'Select FirstName,LastName, etc from Customers where id = (sent in value)' Then use the first name and last name in another select statement. How do I get the values of the first name and last name from the query?

Comment: You can achieve that by declaring local variables(ie. @first_name) or storing values in temporary tables (#temp) inside Stored Procedure Block.